# JavaScript: How to add quantity and see it in Checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a situation want to ask all of you on these pictures below. A `Categories` show a product, when I type quantity in there and click `Add` button. It will links to `Checkout`. I need the quantity I just typed, it will be show in `Checkout`. I'm wondering how to do this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id=@bike.ProductID},FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <input type="text" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, FormCollection form)
        {
            var quantity = form["quantity"];
            // Retrieve the product from the database
            var addedProduct = BikesDB.Products.Single(product => product.ProductID == id);
            // Add it to the shopping cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);
            // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
```

I just updated from your code!

Comment: I'm wondering what have you tried to do? Provide the code where do you have a problem

Comment: What I'm trying to do is when I type 2 quantities of product then click `Add` button, and it links to `Checkout` with 2 quantities I just typed.

`Qty:<input type="text" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" class="quantity" value="1" /> <div class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart",new {id = @bike.ProductID},"")
</div>`

Comment: Update your question with `HTML` and `JavaScript`

Comment: I updated `HTML` and `Action` already. @Pavlo

Answer (score 0):

Since additional values should be posted, I would use a form with a submit button instead of an ActionLink. When posting the form, the quantity will be sent to the AddToCart action of the Controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = @bike.ProductID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
  Qty:<input type="text" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
}
```

In your action, you can get the quantity as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, FormCollection form)
        {
            // Does quantity return the correct value?
            var quantity = form["quantity"];

            var addedProduct = BikesDB.Products.Single(product => product.ProductID == id);
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // The quantity should be stored in the cart as well
            addedProduct.Quantity = quantity;

            cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
```

Comment: Hello, @Bruno V! I fixed it from your code, but it still not work. Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm considering it missed some JavaScript.

Comment: Hello @Trung Pham, you don't need JavaScript when working with this form. From your updated example, I see you're not doing anything with the quantity. My guess would be to add the quantity to the cart. Can you at least verify that the quantity contains the correct value?

Comment: What do you mean "not doing with the quantity" @Bruno V? Can you explain more specific?

Comment: You mean I missed this: `Qty:<input type=""... />` ?

Comment: I've updated my example. In the AddToCart action, you put `var quantity = form["quantity"];` but this quantity is not added to your cart. In my updated example, i've added the quantity to the addedProduct (assuming it has a Quantity property).

Comment: It doesn't have `Quantity` property, and I fixed this `addedProduct.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(quantity);` It's still be the same :(